# Free address data providers for Germany

Tags: data, geocoding, address, germany

I am looking  for comprehensive address data (incl. house numbers) for Germany. Is there some kind of government agency that provides free downloads?

I know that the BEV (Bundesamt für Eich- und Vermessungswesen) provides this service for Austria.

Are other countries also that generous with their data?

As mentioned. I am particularly interested in a dataset for Germany, but also information about other countries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this topic is a part of Open Data SE, and I would like it to be migrated

Answer (score 2):

I don't know whether this a desired answer but OpenStreetMap has a very good record for Germany! You can use nominatim in prob. 90% of your addresses and it will result in a coordinate based on house numbers!

**This plugin is deprecated!** There is also a plugin for QGIS called [OSMroute](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/OSMroute/) which can be used for this purpose!

When it comes to official data I would search on the [open data portal](https://www.govdata.de) for Germany.

I've seen data for:

- [Berlin](https://www.govdata.de/web/guest/suchen/-/details/adressen-berlin)
- [Hamburg](https://www.govdata.de/web/guest/suchen/-/details/alkis-adressen-hamburg16f3f)
- [Rostock](https://www.govdata.de/web/guest/suchen/-/details/adressenliste)

and probably some more. But there seems to be no open single point of truth.

Another possibility is to pay for the data. GfK will sell it for sure.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I currently use OSM and it is only good enough down to the street level. House numbers are missing in most remote areas.

Comment: as you said: most remote areas... when it comes do dense areas it is well covered. But I think you hit a pain point in German federalism: The data is distributed and not stored in a single database

Comment: @Chris I altered my answer and added a link to a data portal.

Answer (score 0):

For Europe I may suggest investigating INSPIRE's Addresses resource:

https://inspire.ec.europa.eu/Themes/79/2892

---

For Germany check ESRI's source for addresses:

https://opendata-esri-de.opendata.arcgis.com/search?q=Adressen

---

For [Saxony (Free State of Saxony)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxony) in Germany, a list with addresses in `zip`-format can be downloaded from here:

https://www.geodaten.sachsen.de/downloadbereich-hauskoordinaten-4172.html

The inside of the archive includes the following files:

[image: zip_archive]

A file with addresses `"adressen.txt"` looks as following:

[image: addresses]

More about the structure of txt-file with house coordinates can be found in the PDF document attached below.

Columns (#12 and #13) that represent coordinates are projected in [EPSG:25833](https://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-utm-zone-33n/).

---

**References:**

- [PDF (in German): Datenformatbeschreibung Hauskoordinaten Deutschland (HK-DE)](http://www.adv-online.de/icc/extdeu/binarywriterservlet?imgUid=db750eba-a0e3-5061-45b0-87471fa2e0c9&uBasVariant=11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111)
- [Staatsbetrieb Geobasisinformation und Vermessung Sachsen GeoSN | Offene Geodaten](https://www.geodaten.sachsen.de/)